# MongoDB Bulk Insert Ignore Duplicate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've Googled around and can't find any solid information on how to ignore duplicate errors when using bulk insert.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
MongoClient.connect(mongoURL, function(err, db) {
      if(err) console.err(err)
      let col = db.collection('user_ids')
      let batch = col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()

      ids.forEach(function(id) {
        batch.insert({ userid: id, used: false, group: argv.groupID })
      })

      batch.execute(function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
          console.error(new Error(err))
          db.close()
        }

        // Do some work

        db.close()
      })
    })
```

Is it possible? I've tried adding `{continueOnError: true, safe: true}` to `bulk.insert(...)` but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative is to use **[`bulk.find().upsert().replaceOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/#insert-for-bulk-find-replaceone)** instead:

```
MongoClient.connect(mongoURL, function(err, db) {
    if(err) console.err(err)
    let col = db.collection('user_ids')
    let batch = col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()

    ids.forEach(function(id) {        
        batch.find({ userid: id }).upsert().replaceOne({ 
            userid: id, 
            used: false,  
            group: argv.groupID 
        });
    });

    batch.execute(function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.error(new Error(err))
            db.close()
        }

        // Do some work

        db.close()
    });
});
```

With the above, if a document matches the query `{ userid: id }` it will be replaced with the new document, otherwise it will be created hence there are No duplicate key errors thrown.

---

For MongoDB server versions 3.2+, use **[`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-replaceone)** as:

```
MongoClient.connect(mongoURL, function(err, db) {

    if(err) console.err(err)

    let col = db.collection('user_ids')
    let ops = []
    let counter = 0

    ids.forEach(function(id) {
        ops.push({
            "replaceOne": {
                "filter": { "userid": id },
                "replacement": { 
                    userid: id, 
                    used: false,  
                    group: argv.groupID 
                },
                "upsert": true
            }
        })

        counter++

        if (counter % 500 === 0) {
            col.bulkWrite(ops, function(err, r) {
                // do something with result
                db.close()
            })
            ops = []
        }
    })

    if (counter % 500 !== 0) {
        col.bulkWrite(ops, function(err, r) {
            // do something with result
            db.close()
        }
    } 
})
```